# Key size change for leveldb

Tags: leveldb

We are using leveldb for indexing data blocks for disks and use one leveldb instance per disk.
The keys for the index are 
The fingerprint was existing in the key for some historical reasons (not known to me)
We are planning to get rid of this fingerprint suffix from the key (as we concluded that we can maintain uniqueness of the key with just inode and page_offset).

The issue is the upgrade from older version to newer version, where we need to maintain two indexes for brief time till the first index becomes free.
The question is, is there a way to use the same old index and change the key size for the new key insertions and to use only  for old keys ignoring the suffix part during lookups ?

Please let me know if my question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some work on `leveldb::Options.comparator`, which by default is `leveldb::BytewiseComparatorImpl`.
For a example you can define a class named IgnoreSuffixComparatorImpl :

```
#include "leveldb/comparator.h"
class IgnoreSuffixComparatorImpl : public Comparator {
  ...
  virtual int Compare(const Slice& a, const Slice& b) const {
     return removeSuffix(a).compare(removeSuffix(b));
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, when you init db, you can use the new comparator:

```
options.comparator = new IgnoreSuffixComparatorImpl();
s = leveldb::DB::Open(options, db_path, manifest, &db);
```

Comment: Thank you sel-fish.
I did the similar thing and it worked.
Modified the comparator to include the length of the key as the first thing while comparing the keys.  So, the new index keys can co-exist with the old keys.  Thanks the reply.